# Accessing RANDAO value from a smart contract

Tags: randomness

is there a way to access the block randomness from within a smart contract or does the value reside only on the consensus layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PREVRANDAO` value resides in the `block.difficulty` variable after the merge. Found this info [here](https://0xmacro.com/blog/what-solidity-devs-should-know-about-ethereums-merge/).